# Complete E2E test of form in AngularJs 1.5.5

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

my goal is to create an automatic E2E test that fills a form and clicks on the "send" button. After that I need to wait the mock api response before set the test as Passed or not.

First question: Is this possible in the same E2E test?

I'm using AngularJs 1.5.5, ngMocks and Protractor\Jasmine.
Right now I'm able to fill the form using

```
element(by.model('xxxx')).sendKeys('xxxx');
```

and click on the "Send" button using

```
element(by.css('input[type="button"]')).click();
```

I created also an api mock for this test in a new js file that I included in page. The code is the following:

```
var testAppDEV = angular.module('testAppDEV', ['testApp', 'ngMockE2E']);

testAppDEV.run(function ($httpBackend) {

    // Api to save the form
    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/save').respond(function (method, url, data) {
        var formData = angular.fromJson(data);
        if (Object.keys(formData).length == 3) {
            // url, data, headers
            return [200, { errorCode: null }, {}];
        }
        else
        {            
            return [400, { errorCode: '1' }, {}];
        }

    });

});
```

Now I need to add the code to my Jasmine test that wait for the mock api response and according to response, set the test as Passed or Failed.
Can you help me?

This is a first step because the next will be to integrate this test with Jenkins, like I did with Unit tests..
Every hint is welcome :)

Comment: I mean, in a first test I wanna check the form validation and in a second I wanna test my controller "save" function (so I need to wait for ngMock api answer). Is it possible? Anyone?

Comment: Anyone can help me?